# ModalPopupExtender.Show() not visible in code behind

Tags: gridview, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

Most tutorials for creating modal popup boxes utilize Show() and Hide() functions in the code behind for the ModalPopupExtender control. However, none of my created applications will compile because these controls can not be found. Been working on this all day and have found no solutions or insight as to what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you installed the [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/get-started-with-the-ajax-control-toolkit-cs) correctly.
If this is OK, from where are you trying to call the Show() function? and where your ModalPopupExtender is placed on the page?